# How to change jQuery mobile side panel from push to overlay when switch from mobile view to tablet view

Tags: html, jquery, css, jquery-mobile, responsive

I am currently working on a jQuery Mobile(JQM) project. I am using jquery.mobile-1.4.5 for this project.
I am trying to implement a mobile and tablet responsive side menu panel with a fixed header.

in mobile view => panel width = 100%

in tablet view => panel width = 30%

I use the following `@media` code to achieve this.

```
@media all and (max-width: 35em) {
    .overlay{
        width: 100%
    }
  }
 
  @media all and (min-width: 45em) {
    .overlay{
        width: 30%
    }
  }
```

After run [this code](https://gist.github.com/nxviyx/4a53c6ca6b3d7b0b4123413d198d9505)  the fixed header overlap with the menu

**tablet view**

[image]

**mobile view**

[image: menu overlap with fixed header]

please help me to solve this issue.. or if there is any better solution to achieve this that would be great

This is the ui that i am expecting

**in mobile view**

[image]

**in tablet view**

[image]

NOTE : please don't get confused with the back button and the close button.

Thanks and best regards

Comment: what behaviour actually you want to have?

Comment: Hi @AmareshSM, I add two images show what type of a behaviour i want. In mobile view i want a full width panels and in tablet view a panel with 30% width like in the images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would have to solve two issues: switch panel *display mode* and set the `panel` width in percentage.

There are three types of `panel`: *overlay*, *reveal* and *push*. See here: [Panel - jQuery Mobile Demos](https://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.5/panel/).
When the panel widget is istanciated, there are different implementations depending from the *display mode* (or `data-display` attribute).

I believe You can avoid to swtch panel type. You would need to *destroy* and *recreate* the panel widget. Instead, I would suggest You to stick to panel *overlay* and use media query to adapt the panel width: the great [ezanker](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1098622/ezanker) has already an answer here for that:
[How to set the width of a jQuery Mobile 1.4 responsive Panel in percentage?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31811073/4845566).

There are a lot of classes involved, because inside the JQM CSS the panel width is fixed hard-coded at 17em.

You can also try to override the `ui-panel-wrapper` class and set the `margin-left` to 30% in tablet-view.

Comment: @NaveenFernando: nice to have a feedback! Some time ago, I had the same requirement as You, so feel free to ask for more detail if You will find some trouble again.

Comment: Yeah sure . Thanks again @deblocker for spending your time and sharing your knowledge with the community :) . best regards